# Dynamic web project option is not showing in eclipse ide

Tags: eclipse

he "Dynamic Web Project" option for a new project in Eclipse does not showing up in the list.
Although the "web" folder showing up with option "static web project" but there is no option for "Dynamic Web project".
I have already installed Web, XML, Java EE plugin.
I am using Eclipse Kepler realease-2.

Comment: JAVA EE must be installed.

Comment: Your release is 8 years old. Stop using it. The current release is 2022-06, which you can download as a whole from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-06/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers .

Comment: Kepler is now 21 releases old, time to use something newer.

Answer (score 0):

use this link to download eclipse web
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-06/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers

good luck